# how to overwrite control+shift+power to start screensaver instead of lockscreen

Tags: macos

or how to start your screensaver?
I've tried few things but most of them show login screen instead of screensaver

Comment: this is not duplicated. 
First, I want to overwrite the control+shift+power.
Second, all answers there are irrelevant cause it's been asked 7 years ago
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯